# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'GoogleAuthProvider' of undefined cakephp

Tags: javascript, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I am doing a small project with Google authentication. Now, this is my first time doing this, so I might be doing something wrong which I am not seeing. I did the following steps:

-I went on firebase and linked my account

-I enabled google to be able to use it for authentication

-I pasted the project data in my file, as I will show in a bit

-and I put the code for the autentication

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script>
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
    var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyArVSWB1OYZYQJEkmc6uIi9jyfmRIW1oSk",
    authDomain: "assignment-da42d.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://assignment-da42d.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "assignment-da42d",
    storageBucket: "assignment-da42d.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "569189156463",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: "G-N6D1788RXF"
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

function googleSignIn(){
    var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider)
}
</script>

<button onclick="googleSignIn()">Google Sign in</button>
```

However, even after following multiple tutorials, using the same methods, I kept getting the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'GoogleAuthProvider' of undefined

What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issues late week and I've since solved it.

Can you point out where you include the following or some other version of the auth library?

```
<script src="/__/firebase/[version number]/firebase-auth.js"></script>
```

If that's missing you can paste it in before your code.

I installed the whole package - `$ npm install --save firebase`

and my config file looks like

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/storage";
import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "......",
  authDomain: ".....",
  databaseURL: ".....",
  projectId: ".....",
  storageBucket: ".....",
  messagingSenderId: "......",
  appId: "......",
  measurementId: "...."
};

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const projectStorage = firebase.storage();
export const projectFirestore = firebase.firestore();
export const timestamp = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp;
export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

export const signInWithGoogle = () =>{
  auth.signInWithRedirect(provider).then(function(){
   
  });
};
```

and I can call

```
const logIn = () => {
 let ret =  signInWithGoogle();
  console.log(ret);
  getCredentials();
}
```

in the navbar.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.

Comment: So I should have posted my response as comment rather than an answer?

Comment: Exactly. Or if the problem wasn't exactly the same, ask a new question.